# Python converting Time Format like DD/MM/YYYY to 5 hours ago, 3 days ago, 1 year ago, etc from strftime

Tags: python, date, dateparser

Looking for a way to convert time from strftime to ... ago, I looked everywhere on the internet and there is a way to convert ... ago to strftime, so I know it is possible but I'm not sure how to do it

input

```
14:56:39 PM
```

output

```
2 hours ago
```

Comment: substract the two times and then you have a timedelta that you can convert to hours

Comment: Don't expect the SO community to think for you. Tell us what you tried so far.

Comment: I did try dateparser.parse('1 hour ago') which prints out like 2022-05-16 17:00:21.431079, but this is not what I want, I want the opposite

Comment: [Arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#humanize) also has humanizing functions, maybe they will be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I tried convert *timedelta*, as following;

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = datetime.datetime(2022,5,10,12,0,0,0)
c = a - b
ts = c.total_seconds()
h = ts//3600
m = (ts%3600)//60
sec = (ts%3600)%60
print ("%d:%d hours ago" %(h,m) )

days, hours, minutes = c.days, c.seconds // 3600, c.seconds // 60 % 60
print('{}:Days {}:Hours {}:Minutes ago'.format(days, hours, minutes))


OUTPUT : 145:47 hours ago
         6:Days 1:Hours 47:Minutes ago
```